# Knowing active tab in angular-material tabs with possible hidden tabs

Tags: angular, angular-material, tabs

I have a tabgroup with tabs that can be hidden with and ngIf condition. The index of the tabs shift if a tab on the left is hidden. I need to display something outside the tab group if a particular tab is active. But the index of that tab shifts when I hide other tabs.

Is there any way to know which tab is active outside of the index that I would have to calculate in order to know which tab I actually got on that index?

Answer (score 0):

In the end I constructed a workaround based on the idea's in
https://github.com/angular/components/issues/14227